# Adjust window size

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying adjust the Excel's window size, so that it shows certain range of cells, such as (B2:K20).

Yes the below code has pixel for window size, it's because I don't know how to use cell range. I have a strong faith in VBA warriors here!

```
Sub win()
    With ActiveWindow
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400
        .DisplayGridlines = False
        .DisplayFormulas = False
        .DisplayGridlines = False
        .DisplayHeadings = False
    End With
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "Show.Toolbar(""Ribbon"",False)"
Application.DisplayFormulaBar = False
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to scale the window to only show that range:

```
Range("B2:K20").Select
ActiveWindow.Zoom = True
```

Comment: ..... Did I just see a real life example of `.Select` being used in a completely valid way? 0_0

Comment: There are a *few* scenarios where it is useful/necessary!

Comment: @Rory I refuse to accept this - everything I've been told has been a lie! \*sob\*