# Adjust window size to set range without zoom

Tags: vba, excel

VBA wizards! I am trying to adjust window size of excel to show only cells (B2:K20) without having to use "zoom." I want to zoom scale to stay at 100%.

```
Sub win()
    With ActiveWindow
        .WindowState = xlNormal
        .Top = 0
        .Left = 0
        .Height = 400
        .Width = 400
    end with 
 end sub
```

Comment: tell us what it is not doing that you want it to do. Do you want the entire XL application to be that size or just the window of the workbook?

Comment: How is this different from [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865681/adjust-window-size) ?

Comment: If you know how to get the effect that you want -- do it with the macro recorder turned on.

Comment: To what end? i.e. why do you want to only show that range?

Comment: @MacroMan I think he is looking for a "non-zoom" option which makes it slightly different than his other question...

Comment: Yes @Chrismas007 ! I am trying to do with in a "non-zoom" way!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, the formula is adjusting based on the pixel but I want it to adjust based on the cell range I give them.

Comment: @MacroMan, Now I am trying to do it in "non-zoom" way using range of cells that I provide. so that the zooming won't be affected.

Comment: there may be a the problem of different excel-versions and viwe style... i dont think you can simply set the 'inner' windowsize... so turning formula-line on/off changes the viewable height....

Comment: @Chrismas007 The other question doesn't specify anything to do with zoom - it's just the answer (which the OP accepted) suggested zoom as "one option". If this was a new requirement it should have been an edit to the original question - not a new question. Just an opinion though, not trying to start SO-Wars!

Comment: Or perhaps you can just hide the rows and columns that you do not want to see ?

Comment: @ScottCraner I made a mine sweeper and the cell range given is what's used for the game. I wanted to make it look more like a game by limiting what cell are shown in the window. I tried using"zoom," but this option option tend to make the game too big or too small because I have different levels and user can set up the game board size.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I promise my answer was in progress before you wrote your comment.

Comment: All good @Chrismas007 - I didn't answer it myself because I was not sure exactly *why* the OP wanted to do what he is attempting, Hence the comment. Given his last comment, it seems it may work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just hide everything you don't need?  This will keep your "zoom" at 100% while keeping the user focused on only the cells you want them to see.

```
'Hide All columns from L to end:
Range(Range("L1"), Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
'Hide All rows from 21 to end:
Range(Range("B21"), Cells(Rows.Count, 2)).EntireRow.Hidden = True
'Hide Row 1:
Range("A1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
'Hide Column A:
Range("A1").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```